# What's the inlineable in node.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, events

below code from Node.js source code **events modules**, and I don't know this comment mean: **This code is duplicated because extracting it away would make it non-inlineable.**

```
  if (typeof handler === 'function') {
    const result = ReflectApply(handler, this, args);

    // We check if result is undefined first because that
    // is the most common case so we do not pay any perf
    // penalty
    if (result !== undefined && result !== null) {
      addCatch(this, result, type, args);
    }
  } else {
    const len = handler.length;
    const listeners = arrayClone(handler, len);
    for (let i = 0; i < len; ++i) {
      const result = ReflectApply(listeners[i], this, args);

      // We check if result is undefined first because that
      // is the most common case so we do not pay any perf
      // penalty.
      // This code is duplicated because extracting it away
      // would make it non-inlineable.
      if (result !== undefined && result !== null) {
        addCatch(this, result, type, args);
      }
    }
  }
```

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inline_expansion

Comment: My first guess would be a V8-specific performance optimization. Probably just there to emphasize to others, that duplicating it is fully intended, and the code shouldn't be refactored by someone who doesn't understand that part, just to make it "look nicer".